# Can I get some help on how to train a Word2Vec Model on a dictionary?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I doing a project, where I'm ingesting student resumes with Word2Vec, and then I need to find the best applicant for a project position. So I have a table with a column for the applicant ID and for the resume in text. But I can't seem to find a way to train the model so that it associates the information in the resume to its corresponding ID.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Do you mean that you want the model to predict the applicant id? This id is probably an arbitrary value so it's unlikely that the model can learn it from the resume (and this would certainly be pointless). If the goal is to find the best applicant for a position, then (1) you need some data which represents the position in the features (you didn't mention any), and (2) you need some labels for the model to understand how to match applications with positions.